# CoreOS : Read-only file system

Tags: kubernetes, readonly, coreos

When moving file to `/usr/local/bin` it says:

```
mv: inter-device move failed: 'kubectl' to '/usr/local/bin/kubectl';
unable to remove target: Read-only file system
```

I already try `chmod`

How can the CoreOS directory be made writable?

Comment: did you try `chmod` ?

Comment: Yes already tried.

Comment: Are you root ? Otherwise can you create a symlink ?

Comment: No, I can't even if I am root.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In CoreOS the `/usr` partition is read-only by design, so `/usr/local/bin/` will be read-only too (unless you mount another disk there). This allows for the auto-updating CoreOS uses to keep the OS current. You can see the partition layout [here](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/sdk-disk-partitions.html).

You can install your binaries, etc. in another partition. I usually use `/opt/` for this purpose. You can either mount another disk on `/opt/` or rely on the fact that `/` is read-write, depending on your use case, size of files installed, etc.

Comment: The default path on CoreOS is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/bin`. By default `/opt/` and `/opt/bin` don't exist. Do `mkdir -p /opt/bin; mv ./kubectl /opt/bin/kubectl`